# Is it possible to pass local drive path as event body to AWS lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to pass local drive path ('E:\local_images') as event body to lambda function, and upload all files in this folder to S3 bucket. Below is how the event will look like.

```
{"body":{"input_folder":"E:\\local_images"}
```

Can such a thing be achieved? Or is there a way to pass local folder path as event to lambda function?
I know that we can directly upload folder to s3. But I am trying to pass this path from application.

Comment: Not sure if get the question properly. Why don't you use a POST request with input_folder?

Comment: Local drive as in on your computer? How would Lambda be able to access your computer?

Comment: If you want to directly upload to S3, use the AWS CLI.

Comment: Maybe as @CharithJ mentioned, POST should work. I should try it out and keep it posted here.

Comment: Why do you [think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) you want/need to use AWS Lambda here?